# Prosumer camera for tethering?

Tags: tethering

I'm working professionally on a photo setup, using a computer, taking photos, and uploading to an Internet site.

Everything works with a Canon 5D mk2 and custom made software written in python using the gphoto2 library on Linux. I'm using it on medium-quality mode (jpeg, around 1 MB per photo) because photos are for Internet, and it's too slow with higher quality.

I have to duplicate the setup for another location, and I'm wondering what camera I should buy for around 1k €. I could go with a second-hand 5D mk2, which is on the budget, or a new prosumer model. New Nikon, Canon, and Sony cameras seem to be well supported by gphoto2, but I was wondering if one of these brands or models is better at tethering. Maybe with improved shutter speed, transfer speed, USB stability, or USB3. I didn't find any comparison on the Internet regarding tethering.

Comment: If the 5d Mk2 meets the requirements and is already integrated with the software and process, is there some compelling reason for doing something different that forms the basis for the question? I mean what is better than plug it in and it works?

Comment: You are 100% right, I could just buy another one and just plug it without problems. But it's kind of problematic to buy second hand in a company (sale tax, garanty, billing,...). And I'd like to do my due diligence of investigating the best camera for tethering, having not done it already because the 5d mk2 i used was already my company property (great camera by the way). I would really like to have some opinion or data about tethering speed, stability, reactivity of common camera brand and model (nikon d610, canon 6d, alpha 77mkII...).

Comment: How long should due diligence take on 1k€ purchase? The salary cost of the due diligence can quickly become a positive integer multiple of the product cost...i.e. two, three, or four used 5d mk2 may be fungible with research.

Comment: Most modern cameras, provided your software support the specific model, are going to be more or less the same.  Some might have faster (USB3) but you already said you are using small files, so I think that is moot. I think the reason you are not finding many comparisons as there is not much to compare -- it does, or it doesn't, mostly.  The software (and compatibility) is more important.